# Changing JavaScript function to work with multiple check boxes to accept terms and conditions

Tags: javascript

I have the below function which works well when there is one product on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function confSubmit()
{
if(!document.getElementById("one").checked)
{ 
    alert("Please read and accept the terms and conditions + Warnings in order to sign    up to Woolly Mammoth");
    return false;
}

}
// ]]></script>
```

The above function shows an error if the check box for the terms and conditions, has not been checked.

Now I have multiple products on the page all with their own checkbox, the problem is if I put a check box next to every product then it always shows the error unless they check the box next to every product.

Can anybody help me edit the function so I can use it on multiple check boxes BUT only 1 box needs to be checked.

The function is called on a paypal button. Surely there is an easier way of doing this rather then renaming the function and changing the ID for every product?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried replicating the if(!document.getElementById("one").checked) downwards and replacing it with id two, three etc. but still they all need to be checked.

Comment: I can change the ID to anything, it's a flat site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is get elements by classname instead, and give the checkboxes a common CSS class name. Unfortuantely < IE9 does not support getElementsbyClassName, so I suggest using jQuery.

```
function confSubmit() {
    var checkCount = $('.myclass:checked').length;
    if(checkCount < 1) {
        alert('....');
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks, so I just add 'class=one' to the check box? Also if there anyway to lock the boxes to a certain form submit button. since there are multiple forms that can be submitted, someone could check a different box and it will submit any form.

Comment: class="one" The code above doesn't submit the form, it just checks to see if one-of the checkboxes is checked. The rest is a different issue.

Comment: HI I tried it out, including Jquery, but it doesn't seem to be working. When no checkbox is checked the alert doesn't show

Comment: try alert($('.myclass:checked').length) and see what you get. Make sure you have the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run the code, so test it. You need to set a different ID for each checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function confSubmit()
{
var boxesChecked = 0;

if(document.getElementById("one").checked)
{ 
boxesChecked++;
}
if(document.getElementById("two").checked)
{ 
boxesChecked++;
}
//same for all boxes ....

if(boxesChecked==1)
    return true;
 else
    return false;

}
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Diodeus's answer is correct, however if you wanted to do it *without* JQuery (god help you), you'll just need a polyfill for getElementsByClassName():

From https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607

```js
// Add a getElementsByClassName function if the browser doesn't have one
// Limitation: only works with one class name
// Copyright: Eike Send http://eike.se/nd
// License: MIT License


if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
    var d = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
    if (d.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
      return d.querySelectorAll("." + search);
    }
    if (d.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
      pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
      elements = d.evaluate(pattern, d, null, 0, null);
      while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    } else {
      elements = d.getElementsByTagName("*");
      pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Then you can use getElementsByClassName as normal:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     if(elements[i].checked) {
        //do something here.
     }
}
```

Where every one of your elements you needed to select would have `myClass` applied: `class="myClass"` or `class="something something myClass"`.